# template constructor and typedef iterator

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I want to define a constructor working with any constructor having begin, end, operator++. 
In other words I want to get this behavior (commented, working code):

```
/*Polyn(std::vector<double> &a) : CalcDerivative(0) , CalcIntegral(0) {
    for(std::vector<double>::iterator i = a.begin();i < a.end();++i)
      params.push_back(*i);
    }*/
```

with other iterators. (for instance lists too).

```
template <typename T>
  Polyn(const T &a) : CalcDerivative(0) , CalcIntegral(0) {
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter;
  for(iter i = a.begin();i < a.end();++i) //LINEA 18!!
    params.push_back(*i);
  }
```

What I get is this compilation error:

```
polyn.h: In constructor ‘Polyn::Polyn(const T&)’:
polyn.h:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
```

why? How to fix my code?

Comment: Also note that you either want to pass a `std::vector<T>` or use `typename T::const_iterator` (actually you need `const_iterator` in both cass.

Comment: Thanks Oli Charlesworth, I confused typename with typedef, sorry for my newbyness

Comment: It'd probably be better to template the entire container, so you don't impose arbitrary restrictions on the choice of `vector` and the allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Nawaz's answer, if you want to support any container type supporting begin, end and a forward iterator, you may want to use:

```
template <typename C>
Polyn(const C &a) 
  : params(a.begin(), a.end()), CalcDerivative(0) , CalcIntegral(0) 
{
}
```

This way it also works for `std::list`s and `std::maps` and whatever. Or, when having C++11 support, you should actually use the even more general `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)`, so it will even work for plain arrays or anything else specializing `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Another option, which is a bit more STL-like, would be to directly use iterators as arguments, but then you have to do the begin/end manually in the client code (when calling the constructor):

```
template <typename InputIterator>
Polyn(const InputIterator &b, const InputIterator &e) 
  : params(b, e), CalcDerivative(0) , CalcIntegral(0) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the parameter type of the function should be `std::vector<T> const &` rather than `T const &`. And then you should use `const_iterator`:

```
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter;
```

Because vector `a` is a const object.

Even better if you implement the constructor as:

```
template <typename T>
Polyn(const std::vector<T> &a) 
  : params(a.begin(), a.end()), CalcDerivative(0) , CalcIntegral(0) 
{
}
```

That is, initialize `params` in the member-initialization-list itself.

Comment: thanks for the const_iterator. 
Anyway I didn't solve all my problems: I want my constructor to work with vectors as well as with lists.

Comment: @jimifiki: Ohh.. in that case, just replace `std::vector<T>` with `T`, keeping the initialization list as such. I should still work.

Comment: I'm going to check Christian's answer as my solution because of the STL-like variant, but your contribution has been of help for me too. I did a mess with iter (I thought I was defining a new "iter" type). So many mistakes in few lines...